# Extent Report no generating for multiple suites

Tags: selenium, automation, testng.xml

I am trying to execute a suite of suite xml file .But extent report is generating only for first suite

```
    <suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite3.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite4.xml" />
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you have put the initialisation of the report in @BeforeSuite and flush() call in the @AfterSuite , then individual reports will be generated for all the suites.

Incase you followed the same and still its not as expected then please share more details.